# PHP upload no slashes in path

Tags: php, javascript, json, file-upload

I am trying to get the full path of an uploaded file. The php code is like this:

```
<?php
$destination_path = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$result = 0;

$target_path = $destination_path . basename($_FILES['thefile']['name']);

if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'],*$target_path)) {
$result = 1;
}

?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//d = '<?php echo basename( $_FILES['thefile']['name']); ?>';
d = '<?php echo $target_path; ?>';
window.top.window.phpUpload(d);
</script>
```

I can open the json file with the rem'd out line but I need the path to return it at session end. Testing with an alert the full path is shown without slashes and the initial letter 'n' of the filename missing ...

Any help much appreciated.

(Click on Names then open nset.json at this [test site](http://glasier.hk) to see what I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 3):

You are assumingly using this on Windows, where `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a backslash. If the filename starts with a `n` then your Javascript code will end up like this:

```
d = '..\path\nameoffile.txt';
```

Javascript unlike PHP will interpret `\n` in single quoted strings.

The solution to your dilemma is either not using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, or outputting a correctly escaped Javascript string:

```
d = <?php echo json_encode($target_path); ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks mario that works fine in all browsers - localhost and host

Comment: I frequently develop on Windows then upload to Linux servers. I always just use forward slashes / on file names. It is officially supported by PHP, and I have never had any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the full path to the file on the *client's* machine? JavaScript security will not reveal that. It will just send the actual file name to the server.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Having solved the slash problem I found out what you said. I wanted to give visitors the option to save to file or c+p from a window. So now I will give a download link as the option instead.